# Find index of all elements numpy arrays

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, indexing

I am using the `numpy` `searchsort()` function to find the index of `numpy` array. It is working only for some arrays. What is it that is going wrong (implementation below)?

```
import numpy as np

#specify the dtype in RV
RV = np.array([
  np.array([0.23, 2.5, 5.0, 7.1]),
  np.array(['a1', 'a2']),
  np.array(['b2', 'b1'])
], dtype=object) 
print(RV)
def Rules():
    global r  
    r = np.array(np.meshgrid(*RV), dtype=object).T.reshape(-1,len(RV))
    return r
Rules()
print(r)

print(RV[0].searchsorted(r[:,0])) #working
print(RV[1].searchsorted(r[:,1])) #working
print(RV[2].searchsorted(r[:,2])) #not working
```

Comment: SInce `RV[2]` isn't sorted, use `sorter` arg.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `array` argument of `searchsorted()` must be a **sorted** one. Therefore the solution is:

Use `numpy.sort()` to sort it in advance:

```
np.sort(RV[2]).searchsorted(r[:,2])
```

Or use the `sorter` argument:

```
RV[2].searchsorted(r[:,2],sorter=np.argsort(RV[2]))
```